# Is there a way to get the Jersey automatically generated plural element name around a collection of JAXB elements with EclipseLink Moxy?

Tags: list, collections, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I am using the Jersey 2.1 API to return lists of JAXB annotationed objects.

I have a class Person

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {  ...
```

In the Jersey API, when I return a List of Person and have the output set to xml, it creates a wrapper called <People> around my list:

```
<People>
   <Person>
      .. fields
   </Person>
</People>
```

when I set the output to JSON format it does not add this extra People wrapper and I would like it to.  I am using EclipseLink Moxy as the JSON provider.  Is there a way to get the JSON output to look the same as the XML?

I came across a field for the Jersey 1.X API called FEATURE_XMLROOTELEMENT_PROCESSING that is supposed to enable this, but I don't know how to set this in 2.x.  And the fact that it is doing it for XML output seems to indicate that it is already set.  I just need to get the JSON to be the same!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

### Java Model

You could introduce a new class called `People` into your object model.

**People**

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="People")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class People {

    @XmlElementRef
    private List<Person> person;

}
```

**Person**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
public class Person {

}
```

### RESTful Service

Instead of:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Person> read() {
```

You would do:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public People read() {
```

By default MOXy won't included the root element.  When working with Jersey you can leverage the `MoxyJsonConfig` object (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxy-is-new-default-json-binding.html).

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonConfig;

@Provider
public class MOXyJsonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {

    private final MoxyJsonConfig config;

    public MOXyJsonContextResolver() {
        config = new MoxyJsonConfig()
            .setIncludeRoot(true);
    }

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return config;
    }

}
```

You can also leverage MOXy's `MOXyJsonProvider` class to do the same configuration:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: I can get it to work with the approach of creating another class that contains the list,  but I have a lot of different lists of things that I will be returning to have to create separate classes for.  It seems that with XML you just get this nice feature for free!

Comment: @user2800646 - Since JSON has a native representation for root level collections, I would recommend using that.